# Unable to Add Features to PostGIS Layer in Quantum GIS 2

Tags: qgis, postgis-2.0

I am testing out Quantum GIS 1.9-master and I've noticed that I am only able to add features to a PostGIS 2.0 layer if that layer is in a schema with the same name as my login. For example, if my login names is "brett", I am able to add features to the table brett.test_table, but not fred.test_table (regardless of the table permissions (I do have INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE permissions on tables in both schemas). Strangely enough, I am able to perform updates to features in tables in other schemas (i.e. I can move or reshape a feature).

I am able to add features fine to tables in other layers using Quantum GIS 1.8 (so I don't think it's a PostgreSQL permissions issue).

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue? I'm wondering if this is a bug, or a new way of handling editing in Quantum GIS 1.9.

Comment: The issue you describe sounds like a bug. You should open a report on http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues . Thank you.