# PyQGIS - load PostGIS layer as editable

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, pyqgis

I can load a PostGIS layer on QGIS' map canvas but "Toggle Editing" button comes "inactive". How can I load vector layer as editable?

The code given below loads PostGIS layer on map canvas & "Toggle Editing" button comes "active" but once I run the script below in Python console; when I press "Toggle Editing" button, QGIS gives me an info message: "Start editing failed: Provider cannot be opened for editing":

```
sql = "(SELECT * FROM tablename)"
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "database", "postgres", "password")
uri.setDataSource("", sql, "geom", "", "gid")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "abc", "postgres")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)

# should the layer be set as "active" ???

vlayer.dataProvider()
vlayer.dataProvider().capabilities()
vlayer.startEditing()
iface.actionToggleEditing().setEnabled(True)
```

Can someone please give me a hint on how to load an editable layer programmatically?

Comment: possibly related to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62707/unable-to-add-features-to-postgis-layer-in-quantum-gis-2

Answer (score 3):

To load a shapefile into QGIS and set the layer as "editable", I executed the code below in the Python Concole:

```
LayerName =iface.addVectorLayer("/Path/To/Your/Shapefile.shp", "name", "ogr")
qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(LayerName)
qgis.utils.iface.actionToggleEditing().trigger()
```

For PostGIS tables [this](http://carsonfarmer.com/2010/04/postgis-select-statement-as-vector-layer-in-qgis/) blog post may help to set up the SELECT statement in order to load the PostGIS table successfully. Once the layer has been loaded into QGIS I assume the code below will enable/disable editing:

```
qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(LayerName)
qgis.utils.iface.actionToggleEditing().trigger()
```

I have not tried the PostGIS example yet. This is my first post on GIS StackExchange so I hope it helps.

Comment: I can already load PostGIS tables successfully but they don't come "editable". Your solution is right for .SHP files. Presumably, because of OGR data provider. But my provider is "postgres" and I couldn't still find the solution...

Answer (score 2):

This post might help in your case. At least I had problems with PostGIS primary key missing and causing QGIS not to be able to edit the data stored in PostGIS.

[Unable to edit PostGIS DB using QGIS 2.10, works on 2.8](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167098/unable-to-edit-postgis-db-using-qgis-2-10-works-on-2-8)

Answer (score -1):

You are incorrectly setting the data source. Also sql string is not needed. The below code should work for you.

```
sql=""
uri=QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("host","port","dbname","user","password",QgsDataSourceURI.SSLdisable)
uri.setDataSource("schema","table_name","geometry_column","primary_key")
uri.setSrid("srid")
vlayer=QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(),"abc","dbname")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

Comment: Could you type the code out itself instead of posting a screenshot please? This would make it easier (and far quicker) for anyone wanting to test it as they can copy/paste the code :)