# Unable to edit PostGIS DB using QGIS 2.10, works on 2.8

Tags: qgis, postgis, editing, qgis-2.10

I have data in PostGIS DB which I need to edit with QGIS. I created a project file with QGIS 2.10. I was able to connect and open the PostGIS database, but ran into problems when I tried to edit DB with QGIS 2.10. Editing tools are greyed out and I can only add more polygons. After adding new polygons I'm unable to remove them. I tried to open this DB with same project file on QGIS 2.8 and found out that it works like a charm. I was able to edit data (like reshape polygons and change attributes) with QGIS 2.8 but not with 2.10. I installed 2.10 through OSGeo4W (64-bit) and 2.8 from standalone package and I'm running this circus on Windows 7 64-bit.

What might be the problem? Is it PostGIS related or is there something wrong with QGIS 2.10 settings?

[image: QGIS_2_10_editing_problem]

Comment: Can you provide more information on the layer you are trying to edit.
Is the geometry well declared (geometry_type,srid) in the database? Did you connect with the same database role? Is there any feature filter applied?
So far I've found out 2.10 postgis connection to be somewhat less laxist, but more reliable. You should also try to load the layer from scratch in a new project to see if the problem persist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please define a primary key on your layer if it's missing. QGIS 2.10 doesn't allow you to edit layers without primary key - it doesn't say a word about it, which I find a UX/UI fail.

Comment: Good call, this must be it. "less laxist, but more reliable" as i said. The main problem of QGis nowadays is that documentation is lagging behind development. This is one of the main themes in the survey the QGis team is currently rolling, feel free to participate here:  http://blog.qgis.org/2015/10/15/take-the-qgis-user-survey/

Comment: Yep, a new primary key fixed my problem! Many thanks!