# PyQgis - Adding attributes to a POSTGIS layer

Tags: pyqgis, vector, postgis-2.0, fields-attributes

After reading @underdark's answer to this question [on creating a new vector layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30261/how-to-create-a-new-empty-vector-layer-programmatically/30292#30292) and @Matthias Kuhn's to this one [on field calculation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34974/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-add-calculated-fields), I wrote a script that allows me to calcultate the mean arrival-on-scene time for emergency response services per cell of a grid, even thought some of my values are null.

Steps :

1. Add attributes in which to calculate mean
2. Sum the average times of arrival per year (I'm working on 5 years)
3. Get the number of years for which value is not null
4. Divide sum by number of not-null-values

My problem is as follows :

The script works fine on OGR layers, but not on Postgres layers. I don't get any errors, but nothing happens when I try to add fields, which is my first step. So right now I have to save my postgres layer as a .shp on my computer to do the treatments I want. Which therefore don't automatically get saved in my database...

Here is the beginning of my script (the part that creates new attributes) :

```
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

# supply path toqgis
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Wien", True)

# load provider
QgsApplication.initQgis()
qgis.utils.iface

# set active layer
clayer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
provider = clayer.dataProvider()

# start editing mode
clayer.startEditing()

# add new fields
caps = provider.capabilities()

if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.AddAttributes:
    res = provider.addAttributes([QgsField("quotient", QVariant.Int), QgsField("moy", QVariant.Int)])

clayer.updateFields()
```

Is there a code line to indicate I want/have rights to alter my postgres layer ?

The most similar questions I could find - [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62707/unable-to-add-features-to-postgis-layer-in-quantum-gis-2) and [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144788/pyqgis-load-postgis-layer-as-editable) - didn't get a solution.

I should say I am new to PyQgis so if you are so kind as to answer please explain your suggestion as clearly as possible.